# 2 intents on post execute of async task

Tags: android, android-intent, asynchronous

Had a clarification to make: Can 2 intents be defined to pass the the same data to 2 different activities ?  The second class (logout.class) is not getting accessed. The code is:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result != null)
            {
            Intent tokenIntent = new Intent(mContext, tokenActivity.class);
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putString("responsedata",result.substring(result.indexOf("=")+1,result.length()));

        tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(tokenIntent);


        Intent tokenIntent2 = new Intent(mContext,logout.class);
        Bundle bundle2= new Bundle();
       bundle2.putString("responsedata",result.substring(result.indexOf("=")+1,result.length()));
       tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle2);
       startActivity(tokenIntent2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems pointless. Why not just do what tokenActivity (btw, class names should start with a capital letter) does with the passed bundle and then bring up the logout activity? If both are actually activities, you'd seen some strange screen activity if it worked.

Comment: @323go The tokenactivity returns something else and sends an intent to a different class actually

Comment: @staytrue this is a very bad approach. What you are trying to is a good example which can be done on android but shouldn't. Read more about Activities, their lifecycle and what android system does on memory need or with don't keep activities option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities%28android.content.Intent%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle%29),

`public abstract void startActivities (Intent[] intents, Bundle options)`

Added in API level 16 
Launch multiple new activities. This is generally the same as calling `startActivity(Intent)` for the first Intent in the array, that activity during its creation calling `startActivity(Intent)` for the second entry, etc. Note that unlike that approach, generally none of the activities except the last in the array will be created at this point, but rather will be created when the user first visits them (due to pressing back from the activity on top).

This method `throws` `ActivityNotFoundException` if there was no Activity found for any given Intent. In this case the state of the activity stack is undefined (some Intents in the list may be on it, some not), so you probably want to avoid such situations."